# WPF GridView, Display GetType().Name in DisplayMemberBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, reflection, gridview

I want include the Type name of each object in my collection from my GridView.  I have a collection which has four different types in it that all derive from a base class.  Call them, Foo, Bar, Fizz, and Buzz.

I want to have that column read, Foo, Bar, Fizz or Buzz, respectively.  Below is the Binding I'm using, however, it doesn't work.

So far I have this.

```
GridViewColumn colC = new GridViewColumn()
{
Header = "Type",
Width = 100,
DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("listName.GetType().Name")
}
```

It does work if I use a String property called TypeName which called `GetType().Name` for me.

Any ideas?  Am I explaining it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke a method using a binding.  You must either use a wrapper property (as per your TypeName solution) or a converter e.g.

```
public class TypeNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, ...)
  {
    return value.GetType().Name;  // omitting error handling
  }
}

DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("listName") { Converter = new TypeNameConverter() };
```

The converter approach obviously has the benefit that it doesn't require you to modify your model.

Comment: @itowlson, Yes, you are correct, I've in the process of implementing an MVVM.